# Trigger to edit a table column depending on another column from another table

Tags: c#, database, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have these table's:

```
CREATE TABLE Functions
  (
    id_f NUMBER (5) NOT NULL,
    id_gFK NUMBER (5) NOT NULL
  ) ;

--id_gFK is foreign key from Salaries table

CREATE TABLE Salaries
  (
    id_g NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    g1_g1 NUMBER (6) ,
    g1_g2 NUMBER (6) ,
    g1_g3 NUMBER (6) ,
    g2_g1 NUMBER (6) ,
    g2_g2 NUMBER (6) ,
    g2_g3 NUMBER (6) ,
    g3_g1 NUMBER (6) ,
    g3_g2 NUMBER (6) ,
    g3_g3 NUMBER (6)
  ) ;

--g1_g1 means - grade 1, gradation 1

CREATE TABLE Employee
  (
    id_e  NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    id_fFK NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    grade NUMBER (1) ,
    gradation NUMBER (1) ,
    salary NUMBER (6)
  ) ;

 --id_fFK is foreign key from Functions table
```

When I am inserting an employee, everything is working, and he is taking the salary depending on that column. But, I am able to edit a salary in `Salaries` table.

**For example**:

`id_g=101, g1_g1=5000....g3_g3=1200` in `Salaries` table

`id_f=201, id_gFK=101` in `Functions` table

`id_e=1001, id_fFK=201, grade=1, gradation=1, salary=5000` in `Employee` table (5000 was taken from `Salaries` table depending on `id_fFK, grade and gradation`).

**After** I will edit that salary, 5000, in `Salaries` table, for example, 4000, I want this edit to be done automaticaly in `Employee` table.

I am sure that I can do this with a trigger. I have tried, but nothing.

**Can** anyone tell me what kind of trigger I have to use and how?

Thank you!!!

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change_salary

  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Salaries
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE Employee
     SET salary = :NEW.salary
   WHERE ....
END;`

Comment: yes, that's right\

Comment: when I update the table Salaries, for example, column g2_g2 instead of 3000 i will write 2000. After this I want to update all the employees salary with the grade=2 and gradation=2 for that function that they have

Comment: have you add commit in your trigger ? , can you try to debug the trigger ? because the trigger you send doesnt contain all the informations

Comment: yes, because I don't know how to make dependencies between tables in the trigger

Comment: but the update you wrote is correct, I am not sure where your problem is , maybe you need to commit your data

Comment: @Moudiz.You cannot commit inside a trigger,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the below example where am `updating` and `inserting` a record to `emp_sal` table and the same is getting inserted to `employee` table via `trigger`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change_salary
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON emp_sal
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF INSERTING THEN 

  INSERT INTO Employee (employee_id,first_name,salary)
  values (:new.eno,:new.ename,:new.sal);

END IF;

IF UPDATING THEN 
   UPDATE Employee
      SET salary = nvl(:NEW.sal,:old.sal)
      WHERE employee_id = :new.eno; 
 end if;

 END;
```

Execution:

```
SQL>  select sal from emp_sal  where eno = 3 ;

       SAL
----------
     80006

SQL>  select salary from employee where employee_id = 3;

    SALARY
----------
     50000

SQL>  update emp_sal 
 set sal = 1234
 where eno = 3 ;   

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.


SQL> select sal from emp_sal  where eno = 3 ;

       SAL
----------
      1234

SQL> select salary from employee where employee_id = 3;

    SALARY
----------
      1234

SQL>  insert into emp_sal(eno,ename,sal)
        values
       (9,'XING',40000);    

   1 row created.

SQL> commit;

    Commit complete.

SQL> select salary from employee where employee_id =9;  

    SALARY
----------
     40000
```

**EDIT:** Am not sure what is your `trigger` but i do see that there is wrong data set up. I read your `requirement` and did my way and it working and tested. See below:

Tables with data:

```
CREATE TABLE Salaries
  (
    id_g NUMBER (5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    g1_g1 NUMBER (6) ,
    g1_g2 NUMBER (6) ,
    g1_g3 NUMBER (6) ,
    g2_g1 NUMBER (6) ,
    g2_g2 NUMBER (6) ,
    g2_g3 NUMBER (6) ,
    g3_g1 NUMBER (6) ,
    g3_g2 NUMBER (6) ,
    g3_g3 NUMBER (6)
  ) ;

Insert into SALARIES
 Values
   (101, 5000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 
    6000, 7000, 8000, 6000, 12000);
COMMIT;
--------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE Functions
  (
    id_f NUMBER (5) NOT NULL,
    id_gFK NUMBER (5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT fk_sal
    FOREIGN KEY (id_gFK)
    REFERENCES Salaries(id_g)

  ) ;

Insert into FUNCTIONS
   (ID_F, ID_GFK)
 Values
   (201, 101);
COMMIT;  
--------------------------
  CREATE TABLE Employees
  (
    id_e  NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    id_fFK NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    grade NUMBER (1) ,
    gradation NUMBER (1) ,
    salary NUMBER (6),
    CONSTRAINT fk_id_emp
    FOREIGN KEY (id_fFK)
    REFERENCES Functions(id_gFK)
  ) ;

 Insert into EMPLOYEES
   (ID_E, ID_FFK, GRADE, GRADATION, SALARY)
 Values
   (101, 101, 1, 1, 5000);
COMMIT;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change_salary_new
   AFTER UPDATE ON Salaries
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
   UPDATE Employees
      SET salary = nvl(:NEW.g1_g1,:old.g1_g1)
      WHERE id_e = :new.id_g; 
End ;
```

Execution :

```
SQL> select id_g,g1_g1 from Salaries;

      ID_G      G1_G1
---------- ----------
       101       5000

SQL> select id_e,salary from  Employees;

      ID_E     SALARY
---------- ----------
       101       5000

SQL> update Salaries set g1_g1 = 10202 where id_g = 101;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select id_e,salary from  Employees;

      ID_E     SALARY
---------- ----------
       101      10202
```

Comment: but I have 3 tables

Comment: You can add any number of tables..I showed you one table..When trigger will fire it will insert/update all the tables you mention in trigger

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change_salary
   AFTER UPDATE ON Salaries
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF UPDATING THEN 
   UPDATE Employee
      SET salary = nvl(:NEW.g1_g1,:old.g1_g1)
      WHERE id_fFK = (select f.id_f from Functions f join Salaries g on f.id_gFK=g.id_g where g.:OLD.g1_g1 <> g.:NEW.g1_g1);
 end if;
 END;
 `

Comment: Replace `g.:OLD.g1_g1 <> g.:NEW.g1_g1` with `:OLD.grad1_gradatia1 <> :NEW.grad1_gradatia1`. Then it should work.. :new and :old are not any columns of your table

Comment: now I have created my trigger, but when I want to update a row in C#, is getting me this error, seems like this trigger is not working properly.

https://s17.postimg.org/nf4ovpr5b/15310278_1533316490059924_1504220452_n.jpg

Comment: Edit the question once again and post the error ..Am not able to see any images

Comment: I understood what you did here. The problem is that my id_e is not like id_g, so i made like this `WHERE id_fFK = (select f.id_f from Functions f join Salaries g on f.id_gFK=g.id_g where :old.id_g <> :new.id_g); ` but I am getting that error when the trigger is fired, sth like "trigger is mutating"

Comment: btw, i inserted 1 person with same id_e=id_g to see if your trigger works, It works, but it is not changing the salary like how I changed. It puts a different number

Comment: Id is a primary key on salary table. No need to make a join. If there would be a duplicate case, an error will automatically come up. Also you cannot select and update the same table in tirgger. So remove the join condition and it should be fine

Comment: Yes, now I don't have errors, but the salary is the same, no changes, after edit on salaries table

Comment: Ok, it works now with what you wrote,  `WHERE id_e = :new.id_g; ` , but my actual id_e is not like id_g, so i cannot make this condition, that's why i wanted to make with id_fFK condition

Comment: and also it is not ok to make this condition `WHERE id_e = :new.id_g;` because I can have 10 people for example with the same `id_g`

Comment: finaly I found a solution i think, with that condition that i wrote before, based on id_fFK, and it works